# How to get the gcc compiler in ubuntu installed in windows 10

Tags: software-installation, gcc

I successfully installed Ubuntu in my Windows 10. But I need the GCC compiler to compile my codes. When I give command to compile the files, it asks me to install GCC by typing `sudo apt install GCC`. But when I do that, the installation fails at 89%. Please help me fix this problem.

[image: Please see the attachment. this is the condition.]

Comment: You will need to post more details (copy paste the message from the terminal) or file a bug report. Please clarify that you are using Bash on Windows rather than Ubuntu is some sort of a VM

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please try running `sudo apt update` in order to update the Packages Lists before you run `sudo apt install ...` I guess your system is trying to download deprecated software Versions which are not available on the Servers. Your installation doesn't even start since downloads are already failing.

Answer (score 7):

You need to run `sudo apt update` before the package can be installed.
Then `sudo apt install gcc`.